# Trying to get variables in hacked category dropdown

Tags: categories, loop, dropdown, variables, hacks

I've discovered a workaround to get wp_category_dropdown to display as a multiple select field. My code is as follows:

```
<?php
$sponsors = wp_dropdown_categories( array(
    'child_of' => 0,
    'class' => 'postform',
    'depth' => 0,
    'echo' => 0,
    'exclude' => '',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'hide_if_empty' => false,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'selected' => 0,
    'show_count' => 0,
    'show_option_all' => '',
    'show_option_none' => __(''),
    'tab_index' => 0,
    'taxonomy' => 'sponsors', )
    );

$sponsors = str_replace(
    "name='cat' id=",
    "name='cat[]' multiple='multiple' size='19' id=",
    $sponsors
);
?>
```

So far, so good. Problem is, the above outputs the input name as 'cat' which is fine and dandy unless I need to loop through the above several times and with a more defining name.

As such, I need to have the name of the input be in the following format:

```
name="scrape[<?php echo $inpCnt; ?>][sponsors]"
```

However, doing this doesn't work:

```
$sponsors = str_replace(
    "name='scrape['.$inpCnt.'][sponsors]' id=",
    "name='scrape['.$inpCnt.'][sponsors][]' multiple='multiple' size='19' id=",
    $sponsors
);
```

So what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot `.` in your code is evaluated as string litral, and not concatenation. Meaning if `$inpCnt` was equal to `5` for example, php will search for `name='scrape['.5.'][sponsors]' id=` and will fail to find it. You can either remove the dots while still using the double quotes:

```
$sponsors = str_replace(
    "name='scrape['$inpCnt'][sponsors]' id=",
    "name='scrape['$inpCnt'][sponsors][]' multiple='multiple' size='19' id=",
    $sponsors
);
```

.. Or use concatenation:

```
$sponsors = str_replace(
    'name=\'scrape["'.$inpCnt.'"][sponsors]\' id=',
    'name=\'scrape["'.$inpCnt.'"][sponsors][]\' multiple=\'multiple\' size=\'19\' id=',
    $sponsors
);
```

Comment: Duly noted. With that said, it still outputs 'cat' as the input name.